# Recursive maze solver

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, pathfinding

Up for review today is some C++11 code to recursively search a maze for a path to a specified goal. This one shows dead-ends it explored on the way to finding the solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

enum { GOAL = '*', SPACE = ' ', WALL = '#', TRIED = '!', USED = '+' };

class maze {
    std::vector<std::string> data;
public:
    char &operator()(size_t x, size_t y) {
        return data[y][x];
    }

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, maze &m) {
        std::string temp;
        while (std::getline(is, temp))
            m.data.push_back(temp);
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, maze const &m) {
        for (auto const &s : m.data)
            os << s << '\n';
        return os;
    }

    size_t y_dim() { return data.size(); }
    size_t x_dim() { return data[0].size(); }
};

bool solve(maze &m, size_t x = 0, size_t y=0) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= m.x_dim() || y >= m.y_dim())
        return false;

    if (m(x, y) == GOAL) 
        return true;

    if (m(x, y) != SPACE)
        return false;

    m(x, y) = USED;

    bool solved 
         = solve(m, x - 1, y)
        || solve(m, x + 1, y)
        || solve(m, x, y - 1)
        || solve(m, x, y + 1);

    if (!solved)
        m(x, y) = TRIED;

    return solved;
}

int main(){
    maze m;
    std::cin >> m;

    solve(m);
    std::cout << m;     
}
```

Input is a simple text file of walls, spaces, and a goal, such as:

```
  #######
#    # ##
# ####  #
#      ##
# ### ###
#####  *#
```

Searching always commences from position 0, 0 (i.e., the top, left corner).

Comment: I don't have too much to say here.  One obvious thing is that `y_dim()` and `x_dim()` should be `const`.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but wouldn't it be a good idea to manually control the type of the enum with `enum: char { ... }`? Since you use `std::string`, I don't think that there is any advantage with letting it be implementation defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few items:

### `solve` should be a member function

Since `solve` actively manipulates the maze and makes no sense outside the context of a `maze`, it really ought to be a member function.

### `size_t` is unsigned

Since `size_t` is an unsigned type it will never be less than zero and so checks for `x < 0 || y < 0` within `solve` should be removed.

### Several methods should be `const`

The `y_dim()` and `x_dim()` methods should be declared `const`.

### The `enum` should be inside `maze`

If `solve` becomes a member, then the `enum` should be made a private member of `maze`.

### Add user validation to `operator>>`

The code seems to assume that each line is the same length and that it consists solely of valid characters.  Interestingly, it accepts (but cannot solve) its own source code as though it were a maze.  Perhaps it is!  :)

### Replace `y_dim()` and `x_dim()`

The only reason to have the `x_dim` and `y_dim` functions is to check to make sure that the passed coordinates are within bounds.  For that reason, what would make more sense, I think, is to have a `bool maze::in_bounds(size_t x, size_t y) const` function instead.

### Make `operator()` private

Because the `operator()` returns a reference to internal data, it should be made private.  Since the only user of the function is `solve` this works if `solve` is also made a member function.

Answer (score 11):

Try and engage the move constructor:

```
m.data.push_back(temp);
```

Because `temp` is a named variable it will hit the version that uses `const& T`. To try and get the alternative version that engages the move constructor add `std::move`

```
m.data.push_back(std::move(temp));
```

The input operator does not make any attempt to make sure each line is the same size.

```
size_t x_dim() { return data[0].size(); }
```

So the above may not be accurate.
You can add a fake set of cells at the top/bottom/left/right of type 'WALL' then you don't need the test `if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= m.x_dim() || y >= m.y_dim())` as it can never reach outside the bounds of the maze (this can be forced to be true because it is part of the code and not part of the user input). This means you don't need `y_dim()` as that is the only use case.

My main issue is that `solve()` actually mutates the `maze` object. Some form of visitor pattern may be a more re-usable technique, or `solve()` would be better as a member of `maze()`.

Comment: Good catch on the use of `std::move`.  I missed that one.